# How to parse arguments when it could be with or without argument for same option

Tags: python

I want to have command line arguments option where user can/cannot give argument for a flag. This flag can be evoked without even an argument also.

for an example.

```
opts, args = getopt.getopt(argv, "hd:vp:",["help","duration=","verbose","plot="])
```

But in optargs if we write `-p` without any argument it will give me error. I want such that I can use `-p` and `-p arg` both in command line

Comment: ["Optional arguments are not supported"](https://docs.python.org/2/library/getopt.html?highlight=getopt#module-getopt)...

Answer (score 2):

You should consider switching to [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) which gives you a lot more power over your command line arguments. The equivalent configuration to your `getopt` call would be this:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--duration', '-d')
parser.add_argument('--verbose', '-v', action='store_true')
parser.add_argument('--plot', '-p', nargs='?', default=None)

args = parser.parse_args()
print(args)
```

And that already includes a full help text, `verbose` being a flag, mapping the long and short options to the same field, and the ability to specify a `plot` or falling back to the default.